# converting h5 file to csv using h5py

Tags: csv, h5py

how can I convert an h5 file to its corresponding csv file? these h5 files are the output of DeepLabCut

```
import h5py
import pandas as pd

path_to_file = '/scratch3/3d_pose/animalpose/experiments/moth-filtered-Mona-2019-12-06_10k_iters/videos/mothDLC_resnet50_moth-filteredDec6shuffle1_10000.h5'

f = h5py.File(path_to_file, 'r')
print(f.keys())
```

I get:

```
scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python /scratch3/pycharm-2019.3/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --port=42112
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['/scratch3/3d_pose/animalpose/moth_original'])
Python 3.6.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 28 2019, 09:07:38) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
PyDev console: using IPython 6.2.1
Python 3.6.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 28 2019, 09:07:38) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
runfile('/scratch3/3d_pose/animalpose/moth_original/converth5tocsv.py', wdir='/scratch3/3d_pose/animalpose/moth_original')
/scratch3/pycharm-2019.3/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py:21: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
KeysView(<HDF5 file "mothDLC_resnet50_moth-filteredDec6shuffle1_10000.h5" (mode r)>)
```

so I am not sure how to proceed when I don't get the keys

Comment: Conversion is two basic steps - loading the `h5` data (or parts of it) into numpy array(s).  That all uses `h5py`, with the appropriate navigation of groups and datasets.  Then write the array(s) to csv with something like `np.savetxt`.

Comment: In Py3, `f.keys()` is a 'keyview', like a `dict.keys()`.  You need to use `list(f.keys())` to see a list of the keys.